# django - Queryset (different fields values in on a single field )

Tags: django-rest-framework, django-views, django-queryset

I have tried union and values. but It seems very problematic when i try to do any nested serializers. Can anyone give me better solution for this? what should I use

```
table Friend Request
id -from_user - to_user - to_user_name

1     2           3          Mike

2     3           4          John

3     3           15         David

4     10          3          Mark

Expected output:

{
  user_id : 3
  friends : [
                {
                   friend_id : 2, 
                   friend_name: Mike,
                },
                {
                   friend_id : 4, 
                   friend_name: John,
                },                
                {
                   friend_id : 15, 
                   friend_name: David,
                },
                {
                   friend_id : 10, 
                   friend_name: Mark,
                },
            ]
}
```

Comment: Can you share some examples of the serializers you have tried which have failed? Their code and their outputs? From there, people can help you tweak to get your desired result.

Comment: I have recently resolved this. I will share the code soon.